# Including Jar while executing Java from Bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath

I want to execute a Java class from a bat file and it include usage of `opencsv.jar`.
Below is the code:

```
@echo off    
set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin    
javac -cp opencsv.jar ArbitrageUsingThread.java    
java ArbitrageUsingThread
```

I am getting the following error when running it. I think there is some problem with including `opencsv.jar` Can anyone help me with this?

```
Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/openc
sv/CSVWriter
        at ArbitrageUsingThread.main(ArbitrageUsingThread.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java` is similar to `javac` for classpath.

Under linux:

```
java -cp opencsv.jar:. ArbitrageUsingThread
```

Under windows:

```
java -cp opencsv.jar;. ArbitrageUsingThread
```