# How to include JAR files on a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

This might be similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363577/including-jar-while-executing-java-from-bat-file) but I can't find a solution written there

Problem is, I am running a java app thru a batch file which needs some jar files to be included. And I can't find a way to do it

File locations:
(java class)
D:\workspace\src\MyClass.java

(jars needed)
D:\workspace\src\lib\opencsv-4.1.jar

D:\workspace\src\lib\common-lang3.jar

Current code on bat file:

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:workspace\src
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;\lib\opencsv-4.1.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;\lib\common-lang3.jar
set ARGS=one two

javac D:workspace\src\MyClass.java
java -cp %CLASSPATH% MyClass %ARGS%

pause
```

Please help on how to properly include these jar files to be able to run the program. Thanks

Comment: First of all you should use absolute paths in all places: d:\workspace / x:\something\lib

Answer (score 1):

> Please help on how to properly include these jar files to be able to run the program

Don't start from here. You should:

1. Deploy your application as a JAR file, naming the main class in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file's `Main-class` entry.
2. Name the external JAR files in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, in the `Class-Path` entry. Note that this only allows you to use *relative* pathnames to the other JAR files, so you essentially have to distribute them with the application JAR file.
3. Use the `java -jar` option.

In which case you barely need the batch file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your relative and absolute path in your script file is not valid...

Especially the relative path in your script...The java file location must be either relative path or absolute path.

You don't need to use the '-cp' flag since you set the CLASSPATH variable.
So, if your jars path is a lib directory under workspace in a D volume.

The script looks like as follows;

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\workspace\src
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\workspace\lib\opencsv-4.1.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\workspace\lib\common-lang3.jar
set ARGS=one two

cd D:\workspace\src\
javac MyClass.java
java MyClass %ARGS%

pause
```